# Any problem with 'Who did open the door?' Justify please

Tags: syntax

Anyone seeing any problem with:

> Who did open the door?

vs.

> Who opened the door?

Do both convey same message?

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to the question in a context.**

Paul: **Who opened** the door?

John: **Peter opened** the door.

Paul: No, **he didn't open the door. I was here all afternoon and did not see him do it.**

John: Well, then **who did** open the door?

The **did** is used with who + did [auxilliary]+ main verb to emphasize the question when the question is reposed, for example, after the answer by one person is questioned by another or in response to a negative statement by a person.

Paul: If he didn't do it, who did [do it:implied]?

Answer (score 0):

> Who opened the door?

Is a subject question, meaning it is searching for the subject of the action of the verb. We do not typically use auxiliary verbs in subject questions. We use them in other types of questions. For instance:

> - "Where did you go?"
> - "What do you eat for lunch every day?"
> - "Where did you meet him?"

but:

> - "Who broke the vase?"
> - "Who washes the dishes in you house?"

[Related web page at Learning English British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/beginner-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions)

Comment: We don't _have_ to use the auxiliary in a subject question, but we may do so (as FumbleFingers says in a comment) for emphasis, or more particularly for contrast. "Who **did** open the door?" is common as a response to "I/he/Jane didn't open the door".

Comment: I have to disagree with you Colin Fine. "Who did open the door?", is not at all natural.    https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/beginner-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions

Comment: And I have to disagree with you, @Terry. The fact that a particular page of an _elementary_ grammar does not mention a construction is hardly evidence that the construction is unnatural. The "advanced level" section of [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verb-phrases) has examples of _do_ for emphasis in statements, though not in questions. I admit I'm surprised at how few instances of "Who did [verb]" I can find in the online corpora; but a couple of examples from there are "Who did invent radio?" and   "Who did write the bible?". They seem quite natural to me.

Comment: Thank you Colin Fine. Yes, emphasis in questions is not that common online as you pointed out. @Lambie's answer put things in the right perspective for me. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Terry - Absent any additional context, though, I'd agree with the main thrust of this answer. If you changed the rigid, *"We do not use auxiliary verbs in subject questions,"* to a more flexible, *"We do not **typically** use auxiliary verbs in subject questions,"* then I might be inclined to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the auxiliary verb *(**did** open)* provides a mechanism for *emphasis* (as in *If it wasn't you, then who **did** open it?*). Note that if there's no "helper verb" such as ***did*** here, you'll often find that emphasising the "primary" verb carries a different emphasis *(I **closed** the door, but I don't know who **opened** it)*. If you don't *want* to be able to emphasise in this way, don't use ***did*** (non-emphatic use of this construction is usually archaic).

<sub>[transcribed from comment]</sub>